# Eigen returning a double

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to return an eigenvalue to a double (`E`). All the code examples use `cout<<`. There is some casting issue that I cannot see or understand. Much appreciated to those who have commented. This is the working code now.

```
float E=0;

Eigen::Matrix< double,2,2> A;
A(0,0)=1.0;
A(0,1)=2.0;
A(1,0)=1.0;
A(1,1)=4.0;

Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix< double,2,2>> s(A);
s.compute(A,false);
//Eigen::VectorXd eigen_values = s.eigenvalues().transpose();
complex<float> lambda = s.eigenvalues()[0];
E=lambda.real();
```

Comment: Please include the *exact* error text in your question.

Comment: @Nicktw I have never used the Eigen library, but, after having a quick look at this page of an Eigen library... couldn't it be that `eigen_values` returns a `complex<double>`? So you'd have indeed a casting issue trying to assign a complex to a double: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html

Comment: @Nicktw I'd suggest you declare `E` of the same type that `eigen_values` returns. The library will surely have implemented the `operator<<` for whatever that type is, so you can `cout<<` it directly.

Comment: That you for the comments. I have added the error. Thank you rturrrado but the idea is to return a double which is then passed to Excel....I don't want to deal with cout at all.

Comment: Ok....thanks to rturrado getting me thinking I have it working

Comment: Please read [ask] and [answer]. Do not edit your question to be the answer -- you can instead write your own answer.